# Chrony set up problem in Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, server

Can you help me with step by step chrony setup in Raspberry Pi, please?

Firstly,
The summery of the problems I am facing:

1.

While commanding chrony from repository (*apt-get install chrony*) its installing v1.6 and I don’f find ‘chronyd’ anywhere. ‘systemctl status chronyd’ says, **not found, inactive, dead**. Though I can command ‘chronyc sources’ shows my servers but not GPS PSS servers as following:

```
=============================================================================== 
#? GPS                           0   4     0   10y     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns 
#? PPSS                          0   4     0   10y     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns 
^* time.campus.qut.edu.au        3   5   377     1   -103us[ -107us] +/-   15ms
```

(I put ‘timepps.h’ in ‘/user/include’ and my chrony configuration file is in ‘/etc/chrony/chrony.conf’, is that any issue?)

**A detailed set up of this attempt is given below.**

2. 

While trying to manually installing Chrony by downloading v3.1, I see after ./configure, ‘make’ command shows many ‘missing’ like ‘gcc -02 -g missing-prototypes -wall pthread’. Then

**My Detailed Setup:**

### System: Rpi3 and Jessie.

First I have made some initial settings in two stages, are:

Stage:1
In the first stage in a fresh Jessie raspbian I made the following changes:

a) In the boot configuration file (/boot/conf.txt) I stop Linux putting serial console by removing 'console=serial0,115200'

b) I load pps-gpio to kernel module (sudo sh -c "echo pps-gpio >> /etc/modules"

c) Told to use GPIO18 as the PPS input by inputting "dtoverlay=pps-gpio,gpiopin=18" into config.txt file.

d) I added this three additional command to the config.txt file, "core_frequency=300" "force_turbo=1" and "enable_uart=1".

Stage:2
I installed 'picocom' and 'pps-tools' to see whether my GPS and PPS are from the receiver is functioning?

```
a) 'picocom -b 9600 -f n /dev/ttyS0' commands start to show output from GPS module that essentially starts with $GPRMC 

b) 'ppstest /dev/pps0' command also executes successfully showing, 'ok found 1 sources (s) bla bla
```

-------------means, both GPS and PPS of the receiver are interfaced and active with the system.

[Note: From this point onward, if I install NTP, it get fix with the drivers and works fine.]
After the initial set up I tried to follow the instruction given here in this link:
http://catb.org/gpsd/gpsd-time-service-howto.html#_feeding_chrony_from_gpsd

---

Now, I installed chrony and gpsd into my system. And always ensured that Chrony is Running before gpsd.

allow 0/0

refclock SHM 1 refid GPS precision 1e-1 offset 0.9999 delay 0.2 
refclock SOCK /tmp/chrony.ttyS0.sock refid PPSS

But I don't get any result. It is sure that chrony does not get feed from GPSD.

chronyc sources results are look likes:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ chronyc sources 
210 Number of sources = 4 
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample 
=============================================================================== 
#? GPS                           0   4     0   10y     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns 
#? PPSS                          0   4     0   10y     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns 
^* time.campus.qut.edu.au        3   5   377     1   -103us[ -107us] +/-   15ms
```

**What I am missing? Any suggestion please?**

Answer (score 1):

I came across this while following the same guide and ran in to the same issue where pps is enabled and working (via the `ppstest` tool) but chrony was not picking it up as a valid source.

The fix for me was even though the pps socket is supposed to be autodetected, it wasn't unless I specifically added it. This also made PPS "work" in the `gpsmon` and `ntpshmmon` tools as well. My `gpsd` command looked like this, where I specified both the gps and pps devices:

```
sudo gpsd -N -n -F /var/run/gpsd.sock /dev/serial0 /dev/pps0
```

Hope that helps someone coming across the same guides as I did.